# How create folder (and file) within the installation of app in Android?

Tags: android

I want to create a folder with pictures just in installation.
I searched a lot for this but I didn't found nothing but a lots of apps do that. I speciffically mean the Android folder in /storage/emulated/0/ or /sdcard/.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, sorry. You are welcome to create directories and files when your app is run by the user. There is no option for doing so just because your app is installed.

Comment: I think you need to add: when your app is run by the user and user will granted permission.

Comment: @VadimEksler: Technically, there are places on external storage that do not require user permission (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`). However, you are correct, that for arbitrary locations on external storage, the user has to grant permission first, and that will not happen until the app runs and can arrange to ask for that permission.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the folder after the app is installed.. However you can design your code such that it creates folder while loading the Application for first time.